# Removing Open JDK

Tags: java, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am somewhat new to amazon aws and I just created a Linux instance. Now I am interested in Java 7, but I found the system is having OpenJDK installed.

[image]

How can I remove this OpenJDK "completely" so I can install Oracle Java?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to this guide. The second Tutorial should help you.

[Installing Sun Java on Newer versions of Ubuntu (10.04 an above)](https://askubuntu.com/a/21133)

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not answer with only a link - instead include the link and a short summary of the information relevant to the question. Links are not permanent, but your answer is.

Comment: This is incorrect. Amazon instance don't use Ubuntu, unless you specifically select that OS.